# Odoo, create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I've inherited create function for *account_analytic_line*. The logic there is that if the field **support_ticket_id** is coming on vals dictionary, it will execute all the code inside the if statement.

```
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        for val in vals:
            if 'support_ticket_id' in val:
                ticket_id = vals['support_ticket_id']
                ticket = self.env['website.support.ticket'].search([('id', '=', ticket_id)], limit=1)
                vals['account_id'] = ticket.analytic_account_id.id
        res = super(AccountAnalyticLine, self).create(vals)
        return res
```

The weird thing is that, on my local enviroment is working fine. But on the production enviroment, is throwing this error:

> TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'

More weird thing is that, if I change to @api.multi (I know that it can't be used in create method, but I just gave it a shot) and on my local enviroment is throwing same mistake, but on production is working fine. So it's all backwards between local and production and I don't know what is triggering this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with code:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get("support_ticket_id"):
        ticket_id = vals.get("support_ticket_id")
        ticket = self.env['website.support.ticket'].browse(ticket_id)
        if ticket.analytic_account_id:
            vals['account_id'] = ticket.analytic_account_id.id
    res = super(AccountAnalyticLine, self).create(vals)
    return res
```

Few points improved:

- if you have integer ID of ticket, we can use browse method.
- unnecessary use of for loop