# TypeError: function missing 1 required positional argument: 'p_str' (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to modify the code written by others.
                                                                                                                                                         Originally written in python2, but I want to change it to python3.
I can't get past the error.What am I doing wrong here?

Error message:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 682, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 358, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 346, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 911, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 530, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1363, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1351, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 396, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
TypeError: trn_hrs_instransitf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p_str'
```

Code:

```
class hrs_instransitf_wizard(models.Model):

_name = 'hrs.instransitf.wizard'

@api.model
def _selection_emp_id(self):
    list = [(x['emp_id'], x['id_name']) for x in self.env['hrs.idenset'].sudo().search_read([], ['emp_id', 'id_name'])]
    return list

trn_ym = fields.Char(string='month', required=True)
emp_id = fields.Selection(selection=_selection_emp_id, string='id')

def trn_hrs_instransitf_Jobtrn_func(self):
    _logger.info('trn_hrs_instransitf_Jobtrn_func start...')
    p_str = 'JOB'
    self.trn_hrs_instransitf(p_str)
    _logger.info('trn_hrs_instransitf_Jobtrn_func end...')

def trn_hrs_instransitf(self, p_str):

    _logger.info("=== trn_hrs_instransitf start ===")

    if p_str == 'JOB':
        trn_ym = (date_utils.today() - relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%Y-%m')
        today = datetime.datetime.strptime(trn_ym, '%Y-%m')
        print('today', today)
        _, last_day_num = calendar.monthrange(today.year, today.month)
        print('last_day_num', last_day_num)
        start_date = (date_utils.today() - relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%Y-%m') + '-01'
        end_date = (date_utils.today() - relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%Y-%m') + '-' + str(last_day_num)
    else:
        trn_ym = self.trn_ym
        today = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.trn_ym, '%Y-%m')
        print('today', today)
        _, last_day_num = calendar.monthrange(today.year, today.month)
        print('last_day_num', last_day_num)
        start_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(today, '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date = str(datetime.datetime.strftime(today, '%Y-%m')) + '-' + str(last_day_num)

    print('start_date', start_date)
    print('end_date', end_date)

    if self.emp_id:
        sqlstr1 = "delete from hrs_othersal where sys_code='HRS_INS' and sal_ym='%s' and emp_id = '%s'" % (self.trn_ym, self.emp_id)
        self.env.cr.execute(sqlstr1)
        sqlstr2 = "delete from hrs_payins where sal_ym='%s' and emp_id = '%s'" % (self.trn_ym, self.emp_id)
        self.env.cr.execute(sqlstr2)

        self._hrs8010_b(self.trn_ym, self.emp_id, 'L', start_date, end_date)

        self._hrs8010_b(self.trn_ym, self.emp_id, 'L1', start_date, end_date)

        self._hrs8010_b(self.trn_ym, self.emp_id, 'L2', start_date, end_date)

        self._hrs8010_b(self.trn_ym, self.emp_id, 'N', start_date, end_date)

        self._hrs8010_b(self.trn_ym, self.emp_id, 'G', start_date, end_date)
    else:
        idenset_recs = self.env['hrs.idenset'].search([('active', '=', True), ('emp_id', '!=', '05')])
        print('idenset_recs:', idenset_recs)
        for idenset in idenset_recs:

            sqlstr1 = "delete from hrs_othersal where sys_code='HRS_INS' and sal_ym='%s' and emp_id = '%s'" % (trn_ym, idenset.emp_id)
            self.env.cr.execute(sqlstr1)
            sqlstr2 = "delete from hrs_payins where sal_ym='%s' and emp_id = '%s'" % (trn_ym, idenset.emp_id)
            self.env.cr.execute(sqlstr2)

            self._hrs8010_b(trn_ym, idenset.emp_id, 'L', start_date, end_date)

            self._hrs8010_b(trn_ym, idenset.emp_id, 'L1', start_date, end_date)

            self._hrs8010_b(trn_ym, idenset.emp_id, 'L2', start_date, end_date)

            self._hrs8010_b(trn_ym, idenset.emp_id, 'N', start_date, end_date)

            self._hrs8010_b(trn_ym, idenset.emp_id, 'G', start_date, end_date)

            self.env.cr.commit()

            self.env.invalidate_all()

    _logger.info("=== trn_hrs_instransitf end ===")
```

I'm struggling at this for quite some time. Any sort of help will be much appreciated!
How can I fix the function? Please give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: When calling the function, just pass the argument required.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @AribMuhtasim I want to transfer data to other table.

Comment: @quamrana  Thank you! I have updated the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Odoo, create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127298/odoo-create-missing-1-required-positional-argument-vals)

Comment: @quamrana Thank you for your reply, but it's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't declared any default type for argument.

Change from

> def trn_hrs_instransitf(self, p_str):

to

> def trn_hrs_instransitf(self, p_str=None):